# Use MacOS Update file for installation on other volume/partition

Tags: macos, software-update, upgrade, data-transfer, dual-boot

I have a M1 dual boot configuration with two installations of MacOS in separate APFS volumes. I recently updated one of them to Monterey. When I boot into the other system running Mojave, it also prompts for an update but tries to download the whole 12something GB update package  *again*. Is it possible to use the update file from the other installation on this one?

Comment: If you still have the Monterey installer in one volume, just mount all volumes and copy it. But most probably the installer is gone after a successful upgrade.

Comment: Do you know where the installer would be located when downloaded by software-update?

Comment: ↑ /Applications/Install macOS [name] but it will self-delete after a successful update. I never looked to see if it went to Trash but I'd suspect not. Next update, copy it over first.

Answer (score 0):

After download the installer is located at `/Applications/Install macOS Monterey.app`. A copy onto the same filesystem can take advantage of APFS's [clone feature](https://eclecticlight.co/2020/04/14/copy-move-and-clone-files-in-apfs-a-primer/) and should suffice if mounted from the other installation.